# Toolbar in google map activity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-toolbar

I would like add a toolbar to map activity. The problem is that when I run it the space is there but don't show my toolbar.

This is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.ruben.my_app.ui.activity.GoogleMapActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.activity.GoogleMapActivity" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the style:

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#fff</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#fff</item>
</style>
```

This is GoogleMapActivity.java:

```
  public class GoogleMapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @BindView(R.id.toolbar)Toolbar toolbar;

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    public static int color = 0xFF1C1C1C;
    public static int textColor = 0xFFFFFFFF;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_google_map);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng madrid = new LatLng(40.428462, -3.704952);

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(madrid).title("Madrid"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(madrid,17));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: remove the style from your toolbar

Comment: you have applied custom style on your toolbar remove  `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar"` and check

Comment: isn't that white strip in screenshot your toolbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes correct, it won't show anything inside the toolbar because you have not set any views to show inside the toolbar.

That means you can add views inside the toolbar e.g.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/top_bar_activity_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/tool_bar_height"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_left_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:src="@drawable/hamburger"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tool_left_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/toolbar_left_icon"
            android:text="Title"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And you can modify the views inside the toolbar accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I solved it with a mix of yours answers. (I can't vote your answer because my reputation)

Comment: Haha no problem brother. Glad it solved your problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

This was the how I solved it. (I don't need the hamburger icon)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.ilunion.a_muse.ui.activity.GoogleMapActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tool_left_title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="Title"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.activity.GoogleMapActivity" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes i just gave an example of the views how u can add inside it. You can add anyview for toolbar. Great that it solved your problem :-)